# Hide/Disable focus rectangles in GNOME 3

Tags: gui, gtk, gnome-shell

By "focus rectangles" I mean those unsightly dotted rectangles that appear around controls like buttons and such. Is there something I can put in, for example, `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` or something to get rid of them, or at least hide them?

Comment: Probably this is also defined in the theme. Removing them, however, would cripple your user interface, unless you have ideas to replace these dotted rectangles by another indication of focus (change of colors perhaps).

Comment: What about an invisible border?

Comment: In my opinion, you then cripple the user interface hampering keyboard navigation, but of course on your system, it is your call.

Comment: There seems to be a GTK setting called "gtk-visible-focus" that can be changed from "automatic" to "never", but it is deprecated and ignored nowadays.